# Using onedrive folder for both windows and ubuntu partitions

Tags: partitioning, windows, sync, cloud, drive

My partition scheme includes a Windows 10 partition, an Ubuntu 20.04 partition and a shared partition for files I want to use in both operating systems.
Since my organisation uses microsoft onedrive, I placed the onedrive folder in the shared partition, it's in sync with the windows client, but the files are unreadable with ubuntu can't get it to sync with the linux client (onedrive v2.4.6-7-ga3c4ba1). Is there a workaround to this?

Edit

In the file manager I see the the folder icon with a lock symbol, as I open it I see every file with a red 'x' and a purple circle with an arrow pointing North East, if I try to open those files I get the error message "There is no application installed for symbolic link files". When I execute the onedrive sync I get "Retry sync count: 1: {filename I have in onedrive}: No such file or directory", three attempts then it gives up

Comment: What error do you get when you try to sync with the GNU/Linux client? Also, can you access the files from Ubuntu's file manager. I was able to access the shared drive from file manager only after disabling secure boot in Windows.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi In the file manager I see the the folder icon with a lock symbol, as I open it I see every file with a red 'x' and a purple circle with an arrow pointing North East, if I try to open those files I get the error message "There is no application installed for symbolic link files". When I execute the onedrive sync I get "Retry sync count: 1: {filename I have in onedrive}: No such file or directory", three attempts then it gives up

Comment: Try disabling secure boot in Windows, and see if you can access then in file manager in Ubuntu. After that, see if Onedrive for Ubuntu works. Also, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1284758/edit) the question to include the error you encountered in Onedrive (but first see if disabling secure boot helps. I was able to access Onedrive files from Ubuntu after disabling secure boot in Windows, but I did not use the Onedrive client in Ubuntu).

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it already is disabled, had to when I installed Ubuntu, and every file in the drive that isn't inside the onedrive folder works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised I wasn't storing files perse, but files on-demand, which is some type of link that Microsoft uses to save hard drive space by dynamically downloading a file only if needed,
This feature isn't compatible with linux systems, only with Mac OS and Windows, but for my use case, that was storing the files locally and use them in both Ubuntu and Windows from the same hard drive, this wasn't optimal, so I disabled the feature from Windows, waited for those that were in the cloud but not in my hard drive to download, upon rebooting to ubuntu. After that, the onedrive linux client worked

Comment: You can accept your own answer, since it worked for you

Comment: Thanks @ArchismanPanigrahi